# Facebook OG The 'og:type' property is required, but not present

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook won't scrape my page, from [OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) Missing Required Property  The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
I've checked all og properties and it is fine 
[META TAG inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwEe4.jpg)

Anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am hoping Heri found a solution.

Yes. I am experiencing this problem, though it is inconsistent. When I use the call in python

```
fbWallPost = graph.put_wall_post(fbmsg, fbpost, fairwork_facebook_page_id)
```

That is when I specify the page ID, I often have success with facebook obtaining the image and description I set in the og tags. When I call

```
fbWallPost = graph.put_wall_post(fbmsg, fbpost, 'me')
```

It mostly fails. When I enter the URL in the facebook debug page

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
```

I get the same error you were getting on "show existing scrape information", but on "Fetch new scrape information" there is no error.

Now when I post pages manually to my wall, the images are not being scraped until I first go load the URL into the Facebook debug tool mentioned above